# Referencing Twitter Tokens

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I wanted to perform a twitter sentiment analysis and I didn't want my access token and api keys in my python document but I wanted to reference them in this manner,

```
api_key = mykeys[0]
api_secret = mykeys[1]
access_token = mykeys[2]
access_token_secret = mykeys[3]
```

How do I save keys in a text file to make sure the code maps correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip install

```
python3 -m pip install python-dotenv
```

Create .env file in your project dir and add dictionary with api config info.

```
api_config={"api_key": "11111111", "api_secret": "secret", "access_token": "2222222", "access_token_secret": "secret2"}
```

In your script.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()
my_keys = literal_eval(os.getenv("api_config"))

api_key = mykeys.get("api_key")
api_secret = mykeys.get("api_secret")
access_token = mykeys.get("access_token")
access_token_secret = mykeys.get("access_token_secret")
```